# How do I move a table structure down in written documents?

Tags: email

I often run into this issue: I have a table (as in data in a table format) and the table is at the start of a document or email. I wish to move the table down the page but my cursor will only move to the start of the first cell in the table, and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> just expands the cell.

For example, you write an email like:

```
hi john, here's the data you wanted

[table begins]
```

Then you remove the "hi" line entirely to write something else (the "I" represents the cursor)

```
I[table]
```

Now if I click away or move the cursor, I can't get it back there again.

Is there any way you can force the cursor in front of the table element ? I've never found a way, there must be surely.

Usually I end up using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and undoing everything since the table moved to the start.

I've tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd>, and <kbd>PageUp</kbd>. Neither worked.

Comment: Does placing the cursor at the end of the table and then pressing `left` until you reach the beginning again work?

Comment: no, it moves it up through the cells one at a time. (that was on thunderbird email anyhow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select the table
- Cut the table from the document (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>)
- Press ENTER a couple of times to add some blank lines
- Paste the table back into the document (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>)

You now have some white space above the table.

Comment: I guess this is a usable workaround. Mostly I just wanted to check i wasn't being a total idiot because it really does seem like there should be an easier way. Oh well. :-(

Comment: @Sirex Yep, it seems a clumsy way to do it, but I have been doing it that way for as long as I can remember

Comment: Thanks, saved my precious time!

Answer (score -2):

Found this answer that worked for me:

Just press the "Page Up" button on your keyboard (and maybe the up arrow key
for good measure), then hit "Enter." That should move the table down.

Comment: in thunderbird at least this doesn't work. (as mentioned on the original question) PageUp moves the cursor inside the first table cell, then return expands that. In openoffice writer, pageup moves by page - so doesn't help either.